# add data-setup in helper form or input PlayFramework2.5

Tags: forms, playframework-2.3, args

I am using playframework 2.5.15 and in want to add data-constraints in form html or input like this :

```
<input id="contact-me-name" type="text" name="name" data-constraints="@Required" class="form-control form-validation-inside">
```

i would like do something like:

```
 @textarea(field = contactForm("message"), args = 'rows -> 3, 'cols -> 50, 'data-constraint ->"test")
```

but it give me an error :

value - is not a member of Symbol

i try to add double quote or slash but nothing works.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

```
@textarea(field = contactForm("message"), args = 'rows -> 3, 'cols -> 50, Symbol("data-constraint") ->"test")
```